# Getting long delay while receiving messages from kafka topic in @KafkaListener method

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-jms

I have one topic in kafka, in which pushed millions of records in a hour from other application. My application consumes those messages, problem is when kafka listener receive those messages from kafka topic, it takes long delay in mid of the execution.
Ex: 
I've pushed 100k records in kafka topic (financial-topic).
It take 1 to 2 hour to receive last records in kafka listener.

Should i use Thread pool to resolve this problem?
Or any other idea to increase the performance?

Comment: How many partitions does that topic have? and how many consumers are active?

Comment: There are one partition and one consumer only.

Comment: are you using batch consumer?

Comment: No, i am not using batch consumer.

Comment: you can use the batch consumer to poll records in batch, for example like `100` or `500`

Comment: You can increase the number of partitions and number of consumers to increase the level of parallelism.